# Issue installing Tellico with Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: dependencies, 14.10

I updated my system to the latest ubuntu from 14.04 to 14.10.
It looks like it removed my tellico that was installed and removed the dependancies :-(
Grrrr!

I tried an apt-get to install Tellico and got the following missing dependancies.
Can anyone assist me with resolving this?

I'm thinking the upgrade removed the shared KDE dependancies/libraries?

```
Someone@MSTUltra:~$ sudo apt-get install tellico
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
tellico : Depends: tellico-data (= 2.3.8+dfsg.2-1ubuntu1) but 2.3.9-0ubuntu0~ppa2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The same issue occurs when installing through the software center, please see below

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 tellico: Depends: tellico-data (= 2.3.8+dfsg.2-1ubuntu1) but 2.3.9-0ubuntu0~ppa2 is to be installed
 Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4) but 2.19-10ubuntu2 is to be installed
 Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.1-16ubuntu6 is to be installed
 Depends: libkabc4 (>= 4:4.7) but 4:4.14.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 Depends: libkcal4 (>= 4:4.7) but 4:4.14.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 Depends: libkcddb4 (>= 4:4.3.4) but 4:4.14.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 Depends: libkdecore5 (>= 4:4.7) but 4:4.14.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 Depends: libkdeui5 (>= 4:4.7.0) but 4:4.14.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 Depends: libkhtml5 (>= 4:4.7) but 4:4.14.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 Depends: libkio5 (>= 4:4.7.0) but 4:4.14.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 Depends: libknewstuff3-4 (>= 4:4.7) but 4:4.14.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 Depends: libkparts4 (>= 4:4.7) but 4:4.14.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 Depends: libkresources4 (>= 4:4.7) but 4:4.14.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 Depends: libksane0 (>= 4:4.3.4) but 4:4.14.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 Depends: libkxmlrpcclient4 (>= 4:4.7) but 4:4.14.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 Depends: libqimageblitz4 (>= 1:0.0.4) but 1:0.0.6-4build1 is to be installed
 Depends: libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.6+git49-gbc62005+dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.6+git49-gbc62005+dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 Depends: libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.6+git49-gbc62005+dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.6+git49-gbc62005+dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.6+git49-gbc62005+dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 Depends: libsolid4 (>= 4:4.7) but 4:4.14.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.9) but 4.9.1-16ubuntu6 is to be installed
 Depends: libxml2 (>= 2.7.4) but 2.9.1+dfsg1-4ubuntu1 is to be installed
 Depends: libyaz4 (>= 4.0.1) but 4.2.30-4 is to be installed
```

Thanks   :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve unmet dependecies run the following command from your terminal

> sudo apt-get -f install

If the problem still persists , go through the solution mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)